# Is this a listview, and how to do this

Tags: android, facebook, listview, android-listview

Most of the tutorials i see available in the net is a twitter alike listview. Need help thanks.

I want to make my app similar to facebook newsfeed. wherein the text is above and image is below. Each post will also be putted in a box. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: And what you want exactly achieve? What feature on picture?

Comment: So it is a listview? I want to make my app similar to facebook newsfeed. wherein the text is above and image is below. Each post will also be putted in a box. Thanks.

Comment: for this you have to make custom listview

Comment: @MeenalSharma Thanks for comment, but most of the available sample of custom listview in the net is similar to twitter app wherein it is only a thumbnail and the image is align with the text. I am trying to decode some examples but it is not working. Help is needed :) thank you

Comment: May be you are looking for this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/